# Toolbar как изменить цвет кнопки назад :?

Tags: java, android

Использую Toolbar от Material Design. Изменил фон тулбара, цвет надписи, но не могу изменить цвет значка "Назад" на тулбаре.

Как это сделать?

Надпись изменил с помощью:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
```

а как с иконкой "Назад" быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стилях за этот момент (и множество других, так что аккуратнее) отвечает атрибут `colorControlNormal`. Чтобы сделать иконку белой добавьте вот это в стили:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
```

Comment: я через стили поменял на  главном окне но в других активити цвет остался черным почему??

Comment: @elik, там или активити другие темы имеют или у вас включен `InstrantRun` в настройках студии и вы на самом деле приложение на девайсе не обновили.

Comment: ДА в каждый Активти вставлен туллбар и в их хмл так как без него не читалтлся тул бар ... как можно через джаву изменить?

Comment: сори сории деай не обновисося))))))))))))))

Comment: короче сося))))))))))))спасибо )))))) +1к в твою карму) на небесах даш мое имя билет в рай от меня )тток не торопись туда)

Answer (score 1):

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788464/how-to-change-color-of-the-back-arrow-in-the-new-material-theme)

Comment: покороче способа нет??у меня икона от материал дизайна строенная не прокатит